# Open Sans Light Latin External Chrome Render Issue

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I'm using Google's own font Open Sans Light on my website with Latin External subset enabled. However, for some reason, Chrome does not even recognize the latin external subset of that font and render characters in this ugly way:

I first thought the problem was related to the website itself, but when I opened the page on different browsers, I did not encounter the same issue. Safari and Firefox render the font just fine without any problem.

I'm sorry, I can't add any pictures due to my low reputation. Here's where the problem occurs: [Page with the issue](http://www.sestek.com/tr/)

How can I solve this problem without changing the font?